# HTML page parsing synchronously issue

Tags: html

I thought the HTML page parse synchronously. But today I see some unusual behaviour. I set background color on body and then added my script below it. But if I open my web in web browser first time it shows alert then after clicking ok then it shows red color.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body{background-color: #ff0000}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(0)
</script>
</head>

<body>
Content of the document......
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The script element blocks further parsing until the JS has executed, and `alert` is blocking.

The body element, to which you've applied the background colour, won't be added until the parser reaches its start tag, which is after the script.

Comment: But if you refresh your page again you see that red color even if javascript alert perform

Comment: @Carlos — That's because the browser continues to show the old page until it has some content from the new page to continue rendering. Link to an otherwise identical page with a purple background and you'll continue to see the old red page until you dismiss the alert.

Comment: I see, thanks for nice explanation. You can add your comment in answer :)